# Trouble displaying image from defined component in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

My image is not showing in the app.js, which I've imported from another file called comp.js. This is what i've right now in the app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextImg from "./Comp";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

  export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={{alignItems:'center', top:150}}>
          <Image source={require('./images/pic.jpeg')} style={{ width: 290, height: 190 }}/>
          <TextImg text='Mt. Fuji' imageUri={'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'} style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
        </View> );
};
```

& this is what i've in comp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
export default function TextImg(props) {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        <Image source={props.imageUri} style={props.style}></Image>
      </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Let me know what I can do for the URI image to show. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the uri property, so you'd need to do something like this in your Image inside the TextImg component:

```
<Image source={{uri: props.imageUri}}  style={props.style}/>
```